# How to add a data attribute to each item in a select using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, select

I'm trying to create a select drop down, which on change, takes the "data-bg" attribute value of the option, and applies it as the body background.

But the background image urls are coming from somewhere in the php script.

so what i need to do is, take a php array of background image urls, and with a for loop, create a jquery function to add the image urls as data attributes to each option in the select input.

one thing is that the 1st option in the list is a blank, so i will need an offset there too.

What jquery function would i be able to use to loop through the option's in a select to apply a data-attr, so i can bind an on change to change the background image.

let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: show some code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my [SUPER DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/QYEh3/2/)

I believe this is what you want.
Use `jQuery.each()` and `onchange()` function

Comment: Great example. Used a bit of it for the solution

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. You can build your own I'm URL array, either through static json or php

Comment: Is there a way to make the background transitions smoothly between changes. I've been able to make it work with background transitions in css, but for some reason, it doesn't work on firefox

Comment: @MohamedHamad yes that is achievable, sorry I'm currently traveling with iPad, will send you updated demo when I get back on February 4th.

Comment: Hi @MohamedHamad animation with body is complicated with just jQuery, the best approach would to use a div as your content body and use fadeIn/fadeOut or animate. Hope this gives you a good clue.

Comment: right now i have a div within the body for transitions, and that div has a css3 transition on the background. this works nicely on most browsers, but notable IE and Firefox it doesn't work. I'm not sure how to get firefox to work with background transitions.

Comment: @MohamedHamad put your code on a jsfiddle.net and I'll have a look for you

Answer (score 3):

Use jquery's [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function with a selector for option elements.

```
$('[name=options]').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).attr('data-bg', value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **each** function in jquery

[enter link description here][1]

```
 [Chek the demo here]: http://jsfiddle.net/5aRvF/53/
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `$arr` is a PHP array that contains the URLs and that you can include PHP directly in scripts (may need server configuration but easier to write this code inline in your HTML document). I also assume that the select has an id of "my_select".

```
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>
$("#my_select option").each(function (i, opt) {
    $(opt).attr("data-bg", arr[i]);
});
```